# serve static files(js/css/images) from apache instead of tomcat

Tags: java, css, apache, tomcat

I am using apache and tomcat in ubuntu server, I want to serve all static files from apache instead of tomcat , I have configured like following, what's wrong in it.

Its serving page when I hit url, but not seving css and js, when I comment Alias and JkUnMount its working properly, But I need all static files serve from Apache.

Shall I enable anything in apache Ubuntu for this ?

Any suggestions

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
            DocumentRoot  /var/www
            ServerName www.tesing.com
            ServerAlias testing.com

            Alias /js /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps-testing/ROOT/js
            Alias /styles /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps-testing/ROOT/styles
            Alias /images /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps-testing/ROOT/images

            <Directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps-testing>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            # Other directives here
    <IfModule mod_jk.c>
            JkUnMount /js* workervs
            JkUnMount /styles* workervs
            JkUnMount /images* workervs
            JkMount /* workervs
            JkMount /*/* workervs
    </IfModule>
 </VirtualHost>

 if I put www.testing.com/images, 

 it shows Forbidden

 You don't have permission to access /images on this server.
```

Answer (score 0):

change this code

```
<IfModule mod_jk.c>
            JkUnMount /js* workervs
            JkUnMount /styles* workervs
            JkUnMount /images* workervs
            JkMount /* workervs
            JkMount /*/* workervs   
</IfModule>
```

To

```
<IfModule mod_jk.c>
            JkUnMount /js/* workervs
            JkUnMount /styles/* workervs
            JkUnMount /images/* workervs
            JkMount /* workervs
</IfModule>
```

[Apache Doc Ref](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/printer/apache.html#Configuring%20Apache%20to%20serve%20static%20web%20application%20files)

May this will help you.

Comment: Same code was working in AWS instance, when we create one more instance, then moved the code, after that its not working